# Comment system with reply integration using jQuery & PHP

Tags: comments, reply

I am currently working on a comment system project. I am able to write a comment, save it onto my database, and retrieve it back and display it on a webpage. But then I am having trouble when I am incorporating a reply-to-comment function on top of my existing comment system. Problem 1: I have created 2 new clickables under each of the comment divs, fisrt is 'no.of replys', which shows new replys. Second is 'reply now', which is a textarea for users to reply to that comment. However when I click on either of them, all of the clickables open up in the rest of the comment divs instead of just the one I am clicking on. Problem 2: I am only able to reply and send my response to the database on the most recent comment div. When I try to reply on an older comment, the page refreshes itself and nothing records onto the database. Below are my markups. I am sorry if this is confusing, but English is not my first language. Any input would be appreciated.

```
<div class="timeline">

    <?php $stmt = $DB->query("CALL get_comment($aid)");
      $results = $stmt->fetchAll(); $stmt->closeCursor();
      foreach ($results as $info) {
      ?>

        <div class="commentBox">
            //The comment markup

             <p class="allreplys">Replys</p> //This opens all replys
             <p class="replyButton">Reply me</p> //This opens reply form

           <form class="replySection">
           //The reply form markup
           </form>

          <div class="replyTimeline">
            <?php
               $stmt = $DB->query<"CALL get_reply('$aid','$pid')");
               $replys = $stmt->fetchAll(); $stmt->closeCursor();
               foreach ($replys as $re) {
               ?>
                    <div class="replyBox>
                      //Reply Markups
                    </div>
               <?php } ?> //Close of reply foreach
           </div> //Close of replyTimeline

       </div> //Close of commentBox

   <?php } ?> //Close of comment foreach

</div> //Close of timeline
```

The following is my jQuery markup

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.allreplys').click(function(event) {
       $('.replyline').toggle();
    });
    $('.replyButton').click(function(event) {
       $('.replySection').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: the selector $(".replySection") will match all elements with that class name, if you want a certain one, try something like "$(this).parent().find(".replySection").toggle()". That means, if a particular button is clicked, go to your parent node, i.e. commentBox, then look for an element with the class "replySection" and toggle that one only. I barely looked at this so it isn't necessarily right for your case, but hopefully you can tailor it to your needs

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. However adding that piece of code in the selector makes the toggling not responding

Comment: maybe: "$(this).parent(".commentBox").find(".replySection").toggle();" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work better?

My aim is to narrow down the selector you are using, which currently selects all elements of the entire page with the class name "allreplys" or "replyButton". By using $(this).parent(".commentBox").find(...

$(this) refers to the button that was clicked, in this case a p tag. "parent(...)" navigates up the nodes tree to get to a tag with the class name ".commentBox" and find(...) will search for the element with the selector given within that node and its children(and their children etc etc(recursive)). Hopefully only toggling one item instead of all.

Though I don't see a class called "replyline" in your code so that might be a point of failure.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.allreplys').click(function(event) {
       $(this).parent(".commentBox").find(".replyline").toggle();
    });
    $('.replyButton').click(function(event) {
       $(this).parent(".commentBox").find(".replySection").toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello, thanks again, I see what you are trying to do now. The 'replyline' is actually there, but I put 'replyTimeline' instead, on my original post, my mistake. Sadly it is not responding at all, I even try going up a parent level into 'timeline' instead of 'commentBox', but still no response

Comment: I am getting the kind of response I wanted in this JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7rq6ovqp/ I doubt its the cause of your error but <div class="replyBox> is missing a closing quotation. Would you be able to create a JSfiddle the html content of a resulting page of your code?

Comment: Andrew, after some trials and errors, I finally get it to work, the problem I had was because there was actually another div called "replyBar" around the 'allReplys' & 'replyButton' and also another div just inside "commentBox" called "insertedBox". I am sorry that I didn't mention it earlier as I thought it would not matter. 
The revised javascript code is the following:
$('.allReply').click(function(event) { $(this).parent('.replyBar').parent('.insertedBox').find('.replyline').toggle();});

Comment: Glad it helped. It's best to give people as much info as you can when asking questions, as you never know where the root problem actually lies :)

Comment: Do you know how to create a chat? I'm not familiar with it, but it would be better to use that than have a long conversation in comments

Comment: Andrew, sorry I wasn't beside my computer all day, by the way, I don't have enough reputation for using chat... Anyway, I am actually using jQuery to send POST info to database, something like the following: var form = $('#replyForm; var submit = $('.rSubmit'); form.on('submit', function() {$.ajax({ url:ajax_reply.php, type:'post', cache:false, data:form.serialize(), success: ...

Comment: As I was typing the above comment, I realized my problem lies on the fact taht my I was declaring an id for my form, but what I should be really doing is make it a class, for example var form = $('.replyForm'); I can see that I am now able make my jQuery respond to all of my other reply box submit buttons

Comment: Remember, using a selector like "$('.rSubmit')" or "$('.replyForm')" is going to match all of them on the page, you need to narrow down your selector like you did in the past example. Look up the documention for the "parent" and "find" functions and understand how they work. the concept should be the same as the first issue so its just a matter of altering it.

Comment: I see, thanks again. So you are saying that I should specify each child submit class $('.rSubmit')  to its own parent reply form$('.replyForm')? And the way to do it is similar to that of  the method you showed me on my first problem?